# ParseJS - .get() not working for object inside object

Tags: javascript, parsing

I'm using ParseJS to try and get the data from a user (from another object) and no matter what I try it doesn't seem to be working, i thought it would be as simple as doing:

```
var message = results[i].get('Messager').get('username');
```

To keep in mind:

```
var message = results[i].get('Messager'); // gives me message object perfectly fine
var message = results[i].get('Messager').id; // gives me user id perfectly fine
```

Since without `.get('username')` it works fine i'm unsure why it's not working. I've used the console to inspect that object and the data i want is stored normally inside the object, even when i do:

```
console.log(results[i].get('Messager'));
```

and then save as a temp variable inside the Chrome console then use:

```
temp1.get('username');
```

It works fine, this is really bothering me because i dislike the workaround.

What am i doing wrong? Why is doing `.get('Messager').get('username');` not working?

**There are no spelling/capital mistakes in what I'm doing**

Here is an image with the `.message` object when i do `console.log(results[i].get('Messager');`
[image]

After further testing I found that the 'Messaging' object works but 'Messager' object doesn't work? The objects look the exact same..

[image]

Comment: What's the result of `console.log(results[i].get('Messager').get;`? What's the error when you do `results[i].get('Messager').get('username');`

Comment: @JakubMiziołek when I only use `console.log(results[i].get('Messager').get;` I get the response `function (e) {return this.attributes[e]}` and for `.get('username');` i get undefined

Comment: try `results[i].get('Messager').getAttribute('username')`

Comment: I'm getting `.getAttribute is not a function`

Comment: Looking at [Parse.User docs](https://parseplatform.github.io/Parse-SDK-JS/api/classes/Parse.User.html) i would try `results[i].get('Messager').getUsername()`

Comment: @JakubMiziołek I get the response `function (){return this.get("username")}` not the users username :(

Comment: @JakubMiziołek I still get undefined like when i used .get('username') naturally